# Backbone View: Wait until collection fetched

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

I would like to know how to tell backbone to wait until my collection has fetched a model and then render the underscore bit.

In the console returns an error from the underscore template that a field is missing. When I console.log(this.collection.toJSON()) it doesn't show any data. So I assume, that the view is rendered before the data was fetched. How do I tell the view to wait until it is fetched?

/////// View////////

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/mitarbeiter',
  'text!/aquilamus/templates/mitarbeiter/mitarbeiter.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, MitarbeiterCollection, MitarbeiterTemplate){



 var MitarbeiterListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#container"),
    initialize: function(){
      this.collection = new MitarbeiterCollection;
      this.collection.fetch();
      var newtemplate = MitarbeiterTemplate;
      this.template = _.template($(newtemplate).html());
    },
    render: function(){
      var renderedContent = this.template(this.collection.toJSON());

      $(this.el).html(renderedContent);
      return this;
    }


  });
  // Our module now returns our view
  return MitarbeiterListView;
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `reset` like others suggested works, but here is an alternative.

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/mitarbeiter',
  'text!/aquilamus/templates/mitarbeiter/mitarbeiter.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, MitarbeiterCollection, MitarbeiterTemplate){

 var MitarbeiterListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#container"),
    initialize: function(){
      this.collection = new MitarbeiterCollection;

      var newtemplate = MitarbeiterTemplate;
      this.template = _.template($(newtemplate).html());
    },
    render: function(){
      var self = this;

      // show some loading message
      this.$el.html('Loading');

      // fetch, when that is done, replace 'Loading' with content
      this.collection.fetch().done(function(){
          var renderedContent = self.template(self.collection.toJSON());
          self.$el.html(renderedContent);
      });
      return this;
    }

  });
  // Our module now returns our view
  return MitarbeiterListView;
});
```

Yet another alternative is to do something very similar to this, except use [the `success` callback function](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) which you can put in the fetch options.

Comment: If you have jQuery included, your solution using promises is the best option if you ask me.  But if you are not using jQuery then binding to the 'reset' event is the way to go.

Comment: just wondering why `var self = this` ? can't we just `_.bind(function, this)`?

Answer (score 2):

This worked the best for me:

```
var ArtistListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.left',
        initialize:function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {
            var source = $('#my-list-template').html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            var collection = new MyCollection;
            collection.fetch({async:false});
            var html = template(collection.toJSON());
            $(this.el).html(html);
       });
```

Comment: This is NOT recommended though as it blocks the thread... Plus this doesn't work anymore, since recent Mozilla Firefox versions do not allow async in jQuery.ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any way to say it to wait but I know you can tell backbone to (re)render when your collection is fetched.

```
initialize: function(){
      this.collection = new MitarbeiterCollection;
      this.collection.fetch();
      var newtemplate = MitarbeiterTemplate;
      this.template = _.template($(newtemplate).html());
      this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    },
```

The last line listens to your collection's `reset` event. When it is triggered, it will call the `render` method.

Answer (score 1):

Collection fetch triggers an event 'reset' when fetch is complete. You can utilise that [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) event

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.render);
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` also allow you to pass a `success` handler function which will be called when fetch succeeds, i.e.:

```
  this.collection.fetch({success: this.render});
```